# how to read big jp2 image in java

Tags: java, image

I have a relatively a big jp2 image. the size of this image is about 724 MB. I'm trying to read this image into BufferedImage, but I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Dimensions (width=95168 height=154832) are too large
```

Is there any solution to read such big images?

Thanks

Comment: Storing such an Image in memory would require around 58G just for the pixel object references, despite the small compressed size. What do you want to do with such a huge image? Explaining the purpose may help us to suggest a workaround.

Comment: maybe you should read pixel regions of the image as described http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466513/read-region-from-very-large-image-file-in-java

Comment: I want to read in order to divide it into chunks. Ideally BufferedImage chunks. Then, I want to process each chunks aside (performing convolution for segmentation purposes)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for the reply, but this code found on that link is still generate the same error..
But anyway I will try to get that direction (reading pixels from the image).

Comment: Can you post some sample code?

Comment: please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27744349/read-pixel-from-a-big-jp2-image-without-loading-the-whole-image-into-memory

This later is generating this error...